# Hi i am new to C#,can some Explain me what the significance of .. and \ operator in the Read Function in C#

Tags: c#

```
protected void TestSetUp(string positiveDicomFile,string negativeDicomFile)
{
        positiveCaseDcm = new DicomFile();
        positiveCaseDcm.Read(@"..\VR_Test_Data\" + positiveDicomFile);
}
```

Comment: Fully Qualified vs. Relative Paths : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths

Answer (score 0):

`..\` is part of the file name and file navigation. It means "up one level".

In your example, it will start from the working directory of the executable, go up one level, into a folder called `VR_Test_Data`, and look for the file name stored in the variable `positiveDicomFile`.

On a side note, the use of `@` in front of the string means you don't need to escape your backslash in the string.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.it was very clear to me.